# How to extract all fields like name, address, mobile_no based on relation in odoo 9

Tags: odoo-9

```
     class Company(models.Model):
        _name="account.company.name"
        name=fields.Char(string="Company Name")
        address=fields.Text(string="Address")
        mobile_no=fields.Char(string="Mobile Number", size=10)

     and another model :

    class New(models.Model):
      _inherit ='sale.order'
      company = fields.Many2one("account.company.name")
```

How to extract all fields like name, address, mobile_no in class New

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select a company for a record in your New class the other fields should be populated with the related fields from the selected company.

```
class New(models.Model):
    _inherit ='sale.order'
    company = fields.Many2one("account.company.name")
    name=fields.Char(related='company.name',string="Company Name")
    address=fields.Text(related='company.address',string="Address")
    mobile_no=fields.Char(related='company.mobile_no',string="Mobile Number", size=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

(untested)

```
class NewModel(models.Model):
    _name="account.company.name"
    name=fields.Char()

class InheritedModel(models.Model):
    _inherit="sale.order"
    company_id=fields.Many2one('account.company.name")
    company_id_name=fields.Char(related='company_id.name',string="Company Name")
    company_id_name2=fields.Char(related=['company_id','name'],string="Company Name")
```